# What is the best authentication scheme for my REST application?

Tags: authentication

In my company we have created report data in Salesforce. I would like to make an internal web application that reads this report data via the REST API of Salesforce and visualizes this. I am now using the grant_type=password schema, since we don't need to let users authenticate. Is this the best scheme for us, or is it only intended to be used for testing?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for the [OAuth 2.0 Username-Password Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&language=en_US) includes this warning:

> This OAuth authentication flow involves passing the user’s credentials
>   back and forth. Use this authentication flow only when necessary. No
>   refresh token will be issued.

This has two implications:

1. You're exposing the password outside of the salesforce.com platform unnecessarily instead of using more appropriate flows (Webserver or Client flows).
2. You can't refresh the session, so you have to keep asking for the password (or store it, which may be insecure).

I do realize that it's for internal use only, so the [OAuth 2.0 Web Server Authentication Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&language=en_US) would probably be the most appropriate flow in this case.

You can login once and refresh the session indefinitely using the refresh token. This most closely aligns the web server flow, as that is the intended use of the flow.

Comment: "I do realize that it's for internal use only, so the OAuth 2.0 Web Server Authentication Flow would probably be the most appropriate flow in this case." is linked to the help page for Username - Password authentication, not 'web server authentication'. Typo?

Comment: @crop1645 You're absolutely right. Fixed.

Comment: I took the plunge last year and learned OAuth2 for doing API calls and am very happy I did.  One other major advantage of OAuth2 is that the refresh token is not tied to the password and security token.  I can't tell you how many times I've had custom API integrations fail because the user's password changed or is expired.  With OAuth2, the refresh token you use persists through password changes.  It's far more secure to force the user to change their password regularly, especially a user with enough access to do anything in the API.